# Disabling GPU and using onboard graphics on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card, switchable-graphics

I have got an Asus N53 laptop with Core i7 2630QM CPU and nVidia GT 550M GPU. On Windows, i watch movies and play games. Which i need GPU. But on Ubuntu, i just develop web sites only use Netbeans and Chrome. But ubuntu uses GPU as default which means more heating, more noise, more power consumption etc.

How can i disable nVidia on ubuntu and use only intel onboard graphics?

Comment: The nVidia GT 550M GPU is soldered to the motherboard in the Asus N53, so this **is** the onboard graphics. The Intel graphics you are talking about is the GPU inside the CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install an application to automate using the [Nvidia Optimus technology](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html), which allows you to switch between the integrated and discrete GPU.  As far as I'm aware, Nvidia provides support for this feature *only* in their Windows drivers.

Some of these applications include [The Ironhide Project](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/610) or [The Bumblebee Project](https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee).

---

If you're up for a bit of a read, [this website](https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux) covers many of the aspects related to disabling the card, and being able to
use it when active.

Comment: Would that solution also work on desktops?

Comment: @wleoncio I don't believe any desktop motherboards/GPUs support Optimus technology to be honest, although some motherboards support switching between a dedicated graphics card and an in-CPU-die GPU (e.g. the LucidLogix® Virtu technology available on the ASUS P8Z68-V Pro, which works with any CPU with an on-die GPU like the Intel i7 2600k).